# Don't getting JSON data properly

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting this output of json by doing this

```
$.get('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
      alert(data);
});
```

Output of this is :

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object]
```

and I tried ouput of getDataPartySize.php like below and getDataPartySize.php have also this `header("Content-type: text/json")`;

```
[{"name":"waqar","size":"3"},{"name":"waqas","size":"8"},{"name":"jahangir","size":"6"},{"name":"wawar","size":"3"},
 {"name":"basit","size":"5"},{"name":"basit","size":"5"},{"name":"Ali","size":"4"},
 {"name":"basit","size":"4"},{"name":"Malik","size":"5"},{"name":"basit","size":"5"},
 {"name":"Kashif","size":"7"},{"name":"test","size":"5"},{"name":"Ch","size":"7"},
 {"name":"first","size":"10"},{"name":"2nd","size":"6"},{"name":"qasim","size":"10"},
 {"name":"saleem","size":"14"},{"name":"testing","size":"16"},
 {"name":"kashif","size":"10"},{"name":"Ch","size":"14"},{"name":"saleem","size":"6"},
 {"name":"new","size":"1"},{"name":"abc","size":"2"},{"name":"lahori","size":"3"},
 {"name":"newpak","size":"1"},{"name":"abc","size":"2"},{"name":"tabaq","size":"6"}
]
```

I am using jQuery. I don't know what the problem is.

**EDIT:** also tried this, getting same output.

```
$.getJSON("getDataPartySize.php",function(result){
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: It may not matter, but what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Try to `console.log` instead of `alert`.  `alert` tries to convert the objects to strings (which is `[object Object]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify the dataType

```
$.get('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
      alert(data);
},'json');
```

or parse the json manually

```
$.get('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      alert(json);
//i would prefer 
//console.log(json);
//because alert tries to convert the objects to strings as mentioned by @Rocket in comments
});
```

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/82BFZ/3/)

Comment: The `dataType` is optional, jQuery will detect what it is and parse accordingly.  He has `Content-type: text/json`, so jQuery will automagically realize it's JSON, but adding the dataType is always a good idea.

Comment: @Rocket i missed the `header("Content-type: text/json");` of the question thanks for correcting

Comment: Adding `'json'` is a good idea anyway, it never hurt to be too verbose.

Comment: One more thing, i want to get the value of each field as traverse one object like {"name":"abc","size":"4"} and get the value of name and size on one iteration of $.each ? is it possible ?

Comment: @ClusterStorms: `$.each(data, function(){console.log(this.name+'='+this.size);})`;

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is correct, you're seeing `[object Object]` because `alert` tries to convert the objects to strings.  `alert` isn't the best for debugging.  You should use `console.log` and then look in your JS console.

If you use `console.log`, you'll see it's just fine.  Try to `alert(data[0].name)`, and you'll see it works fine.

P.S. You should set the type to 'json' in the `$.get`.  jQuery will automagically detect that it's JSON because you have `Content-type: text/json`, but it's a good idea to add it anyway.

```
$.get('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Or use `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are getting the JSON data properly, but you need to loop through and go through each object.

jQuery has a built in each method that would be useful for this:

```
$.get('getDataPartySize.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, item){
        alert(item.name);
    });
},'json');
```

That would then alert the property 'name' for each object.

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop on the dataset:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
alert(data[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try  $.getJSON() and see what you get